# color names of elements of an Rbrewer palette

Tags: r, ggplot2, colors

I would like to use a diverging palette similar to "RdYlBu" in the RColorBrewer Package for coloring the points of a scatter plot.
However, I would like the middle color of the "RdYlBu" palette (the 6th color) to be "Green" and all other colors from the "RdYlBu" are just perfect.

I am able to generate the plot using "RdYlBu" using the following specification:

```
scale_colour_manual(values = brewer.pal(11,"RdYlBu"), name="Glc mmol/L", labels=c("<1.5", "1.5-2", "2-2.5", "2.5-3", "3-3.5", "3.5-5.5", "5.5-7.5", "7.5-10", "10-15", "15-20")) +
```

To get the same colors with the middle color (6th to be green), I believe I need to know the color "values" or names so that I can manually specify the colors. Something like this:

```
scale_colour_manual(values = c(#first five values of RdYlBu#, "Green", #last 5 five values of "RdYlBu"#), #etc... etc....#)
```

My question is how can I find out what the values of the colors of RdYlBu are?

I really tried researching this for a long time and found lots of interesting things about colors, but nothing that addresses my specific question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could try something along

```
library(RColorBrewer)
br_pal <- brewer.pal(11,"RdYlBu")
my_pal <- c(head(br_pal, 5), "Green", tail(br_pal, 5))
# just for displaying old and new palette - not required for solution
scales::show_col(br_pal)
scales::show_col(my_pal)

scale_colour_manual(values = my_pal, #etc... etc....#)
```

#### Explanation

You wanted

> #first five values of RdYlBu#, "Green", #last 5 five values of "RdYlBu"#

`head(x, 5)` will get the first 5 elements of vector `x`, `tail(x, 5)` the last 5 elements. Concatenate the pieces with `c(...)` and you're done.

Comment: Thank you, this works. Can't upvote now, not enough reputation, much appreciated.

Comment: Thank you for accepting the answer. May be, you can upvote sometimes later ;-)